# Как создать новое static поле в наследнике или КАК СЭКОНОМИТЬ пару байт?

Tags: c#

У меня имеется класс Packet, от которого наследуются другие Packet'ы.

```
public abstract class Packet
{
    public static byte Id;

    public virtual void Write(ref RawPacket packet)
    {
        packet.WriteByte(Id);
    }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы для каждого наследника этого класса был свой static Id, чтобы сэкономить пару байт? Пытался выносить Id в Static Generic классы, но тогда метод Write не видит Id.

Например у меня имеется PacketA, PacketB, которые наследуются от класса Packet. И ко мне по сети приходит массив байт, первый элемент которого указывает на тип пакета, то есть Id. И с помощью Id, используя Dictionary<byte, Type> я могу обратится к экземпляру класса PacketA или B и узнать каким способом считывать этот массив. А экземпляры пакетов PacketA, PacketB очень часто создаются, потому Id в экземплярах одних и тех же PacketA или PacketB будут расходовать лишний байт памяти на каждое Id.

Comment: почему важно делать это статикой?

Comment: У вас не должно быть статика там вовсе. "Пакет" - это один конкретный объект, как допустим, сотрудник, у которого есть свое имя, должность, зарплата, сделав что-то статичным, вы делаете это общим, то есть условно делая у сотрудника зарплату статичной - у всех сотрудников будет одна и таж зарплата. Поэтому статика в данном случае, это странное решение, яб сказал даже вредное.

Comment: Статика к ООП не имеет никакого отношения. Начните с рассказа о том, что вы вообще хотите сделать. На поставленный вопрос ответ "никак".

Comment: АлексейШиманский  Например у меня имеется PacketA, PacketB, которые наследуются от класса Packet. И ко мне по сети приходит массив байт, первый элемент которого указывает на тип пакета, то есть Id. И с помощью Id, используя Dictionary<byte, Type> я могу обратится к экемпляру класса PacketA или B и узнать каким способом считывать этот массив. А экземпляры пакетов PacketA, PacketB очень часто создаются, потому Id в экземплярах одних и тех же PacketA или PacketB будут раскодовать лишний байт памяти на каждое Id.

Comment: @Diyabya всё равное не вижу причин для использования static.  Вы кажется пытаетесь экономить на спичках

Comment: Во-первых не 1 байт, а 4 байта, вы забыли про выравнивание. Во-вторых если хотите реальной производительности и минимального расхода памяти, используйте структуры, а не классы и никакого наследования, чтобы избежать виртуализации. Если заголовок пакета фиксированной длины, его можно вообще напрямую читать в участок памяти, который использовать как структуру данных без затрат на копирование данных. Но такие штуки надо разбирать и писать имея реальную задачу, а не абстрактную.

Comment: А сколько у вас всего разных типов пакетов? Дело в том, что `Dictionary` - **очень** тяжеловесный класс. Если у вас меньше десяти типов пакетов, то словарь принесёт такой оверхед, что экономия нескольких байтов теряется на его фоне.

Comment: По-моему, у вас должен быть отдельный класс-диспетчер, который хранит в себе информацию о типах и именно он по первому байту выбирает тип и перенаправляет работу нужному типу (методу), который далее осуществляет чтение/запись.

Comment: Мне кажется, стоит взглянуть на [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/pattern-matching) и [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/patterns-objects) (угу, люблю pattern matching).

Comment: В комментариях есть хорошие рекомендации, но нет ответа на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, можно применить [CRTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```cs
public abstract class Packet<TSelf> where TSelf : Packet<TSelf>
{
    public static byte Id;

    public virtual void Write(ref RawPacket packet)
    {
        packet.WriteByte(Id);
    }
}
```

Использовать нужно так:

```cs
public class Ipv4Packet : Packet<Ipv4Packet>
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Заметьте, что с CRTP различные пакеты не имеют общего предка, так что если он реально нужен, вам понадобится унаследовать `Packet<TSelf>` от нешаблонного `Packet`:

```cs
public abstract class Packet
{
    // общая функциональность тут, возможно как abstract
}

public abstract class Packet<TSelf> : Packet where TSelf : Packet<TSelf>
{
    // ...
```

Comment: С таким подходом virtual можно убрать. Супер!

Comment: @rotabor Спасибо!

Comment: Аааааа, а я только на неприятность наткнулся, и она как раз решается последним добавлением.

Comment: @rotabor вот и хорошо 8-)

Comment: К сожалению, инициализировать статическую переменную в контексте класса-наследника можно только в нём самом, но не в базовом классе.

Comment: @rotabor Не совсем понимаю, а можно пример с кодом?

Comment: Да https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1553354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!! Это именно то, что я искал.

Comment: @Diyabya Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно объявлять Id в каждом наследнике:

```
public class PacketA : Packet
{
    public static byte Id;

    public override void Write(ref RawPacket packet)
    {
        packet.WriteByte(Id);
    }
}
```

Скорее всего, Id как-то связан с классом, так что он может быть константой.

Проверил CRTP by VladD:

```
using System;
static class Programm {
    public abstract class Packet<TSelf> where TSelf : Packet<TSelf> {
        public static byte Id;
        public void Write() { Console.WriteLine(Id); }
    }
    public class Ipv4Packet : Packet<Ipv4Packet> {
        static Ipv4Packet() { Id = 1; }
    }
    public class Ipv6Packet : Packet<Ipv6Packet> {
        static Ipv6Packet() { Id = 2; }
    }
    static void Main() {
        var a1 = new Ipv4Packet(); a1.Write();
        var a2 = new Ipv6Packet(); a2.Write();
        a1.Write();
        a2.Write();
    }
}

-->

1
2
1
2
```

Можно взять на вооружение!

Answer (score 2):

Можно вместо статики прописать в базовом классе абстрактное свойство:

```
public abstract class Packet
{
    public abstract byte Id
    {
        get;
    }

    public virtual void Write (ref RawPacket packet)
    {
        packet.WriteByte(Id);
    }
}
```

И имплементировать это свойство в производных классах:

```
public class PacketA : Packet
{
    public override byte Id => 1;
}

public class PacketB : Packet
{
    public override byte Id => 2;
}
```